# Python: Comprehension lists , accessing outer loop/

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension, nested-loops

This is probably simple, but, I cannot find it for some reason. For example:

```
def fnc(dt):
    print dt
    return;



#[(fnc(y)) for y in range(5) for x in range(5)]


for x in range(0, 5):
    fnc(x)
    for y in range(0, 5):
        fnc(y)
```

I would like the commented out line to have similar behaviour with the double nested loop bellow it. Is this possible? I give up, I cannot find it! Thanks for any input.

Comment: Erm, misread the q.

Comment: Just remove `fnc(x)`.

Comment: Why do you want to execute this within a list comprehension statement when you're not returning/storing any data?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ fnc(x) and fnc(y) can be any kind of function, i want to use it the commented out oneliner.

Comment: @Mkptidx What do you think the one liner does?

Comment: You switched the nesting around. In a list comprehension, `for y in range(5) for x in range(5)` nests the `x` loop inside the `y` loop.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ a more efficient way to write for loops without wasting too much space? :D

Comment: Why are you using a list comprehension for side effects? List comprehensions are for building lists.

Comment: @Mkptidx _No_. Inefficient because you return nothing and create a list in memory with nothing but `None`s as its elements -- a wasteful operation, nothing efficient or conservative about it except less lines in your source.

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?? There is a similar example that shows how a *double loop* comprehension expands to a *normal* loop.

Comment: Are you interested in the functions' return value or just their side effect.  If it is too hard, just leave it as an expanded for loop or you might not be able to understand it later.

Answer (score 3):

You have to used nested list comprehensions to achieve the same result:

```
[(fnc(x),[fnc(y) for y in range(5)]) for x in range(5)]
```

I used a tuple `(fnc(x), [...])` to output `x` before performing the list comprehension for `y`.

---

P.S.: Don't actually use this. Stick to your loops.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a list comprehension here. List comprehensions are for building lists **not for side effects**, as you have in your *for* loop. Any solution that provides the same result using a list comp. (like the one below) will produce a useless list of `None`s:

```
[fnc(y) for x in range(5) if fnc(x) or 1 for y in range(5)]
```

The code is **unpythonic** and unreadable. You should never use it. `fnc(x)` is always evaluated while evaluating the `if`, and the branch is always taken because it is short-circuited with a *truthy* value using `or`, so that the nested loop always executes `∀ x`.

The Pythonic way is to use a vanilla *for* like you've done.

Comment: Cheers for input, what's the most pythonic way to write this nested loop ?

Comment: @Mkptidx Exactly the way you have it. Except maybe replace `range(0, 5)` with `range(5)`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I find matlab more flexible in vectorization

Comment: @Mkptidx: If your primary goal in writing this code is to not be bored by it, you should communicate that in your question. You will need to be careful to make it objectively answerable and on-topic, though; it is likely to be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: @Mkptidx This is more of a rule of thumb than a rule of the language. It's like saying to not use a gun to kill mosquitos.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye my goal for tonight, is, at least 10 downvotes. On topic, It's always fun to kill a mosquito with a gun, given the chance!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is probably technically possible (I'm thinking of a class with an overridden iterator that calls func() in the iteration, although I'm not sure if this is actually implementable).
The implementation, however, would be an aberration.

List comprehensions are intended as a fast way to filter, combine and/or process data in a list to generate another one. You should think of them as a way to quickly apply a function to all the data in the list, appending each time the function results to the output list.
This is why there's no syntax to, say, do assignments or external function calls in comprehensions. If you need to call a function in the inner loop before processing the data, you're better off with the nested loop approach (which is also much more readable than anything equivalent hacked to work in a comprehension)